# jQuery - How to make sticky header return to default state on top of the page without scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have sticky header and a stats counter on my page, and when fires if i return to top of the page, header won't return to default.

Here is the code

```
    //here is counter

    $(function () {

      var screenSize = $(window).height();
      var scrollHeight = ( screenSize ) + 100;

      function comma(num) {
        var parts = num.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    };

        var fx = function fx() {
        $(".stat-number").each(function (i, el) {
            var data = parseInt(this.dataset.n, 10);
            var props = {
                "from": {
                    "count": 0
                },
                    "to": {
                    "count": data
                }
            };
            $(props.from).animate(props.to, {
                duration: 1000 * 1,
                step: function (now, fx) {
                    $(el).text(comma(Math.ceil(now)));
                },
                complete:function() {
                    if (el.dataset.sym !== undefined) {
                      el.textContent = el.textContent.concat(el.dataset.sym)
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        };


        var reset = function reset() {
            console.log($(this).scrollTop())
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > scrollHeight) {
                $(this).off("scroll");
              fx()
            }

        };

        $(window).on("scroll", reset);

    });

    //here is sticky header

     $(function () {

      $(window).scroll(function(){
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2) {
            $('.header').addClass('fixed-head');
          } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('fixed-head');
          }
      });

});
```

I think the problem is they both use 'scroll' event, and counter have this line

```
$(this).off("scroll");
```

So my question is, is there way to check if user is on top of the page without 'scroll' event?